# What kind of statistical test would give me the change in likelihood over a period of time for the target variable?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, likelihood

Here's a sample of data

```
     a_id b_received brand_id c_consumed type_received       date  output
0    sam       soap     bill        oil       edibles 2011-01-01       1
1    sam        oil    chris        NaN       utility 2011-01-02       1
2    sam      brush      dan       soap       grocery 2011-01-03       0
3  harry        oil      sam      shoes      clothing 2011-01-04       1
4  harry      shoes     bill        oil       edibles 2011-01-05       1
5  alice       beer      sam       eggs     breakfast 2011-01-06       0
6  alice      brush    chris      brush      cleaning 2011-01-07       1
7  alice       eggs      NaN        NaN       edibles 2011-01-08       1
```

For each day there's an output, I want to calculate the likelihood of the output for each day over the period of 90 days that the data is given, so as to understand if the likelihood of a person consuming a product has changed over time. The output column tells me if the person consumed the product that he received or not.

I need to see over a period of time, how the likelihood of a person consuming a product has changed over time? What kind of statistical method could help me build such a graph which maps over the past 90 days(the total time period of the data) the likelihood of a person consuming a product given the brand and type. The date here refers to the day the product was consumed.

The problem that I am facing is how do I calculate the likelihood for each day. I need to calculate the likelihood by brand_id, by type_received.

Is there any method to do this, I can code, but I need to know what I am doing, statistically speaking.